# How to respond with 404 from Node.js when serving static files with NGINX?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a Node.js app running on port 3000 and using NGINX as a proxy. Static files are also being served by NGINX. The conf in sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.dev;

    location ~ ^/(img/|js/|css/|robots.txt|favicon.ico) {
        root /srv/nodejs/myapp/public;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine at the moment. But when a non-existing static file is requested (/css/doesntexist.css) I get a the default NGINX 404 page.

I know it's possible to redirect the user tot a custom 404 page (eg. /404.html), but I want to keep the URL pointing to the non-existing path while displaying a custom 404 from my Node app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `error_page`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Guess I should've RTFM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with the following.

```
location ~ ^/(img/|js/|css/|robots.txt|favicon.ico) {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    error_page 404 = @not_found;
}

location @not_found {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

Which is based on an example from the [NGINX documentation for the error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) option.